# pipe, when parent close fd[1], what the child will get from fd[0]?

Tags: c, linux, pipe

```
#define STACK_SIZE (1024 * 1024)

static char container_stack[STACK_SIZE];
char* const container_args[] = {
    "/bin/bash",
    NULL
};

int pipefd[2];

...

int container_main(void* arg)
{

    ...

    char ch;
    close(pipefd[1]);
    read(pipefd[0], &ch, 1);

    printf("Get EOF [%d] from parent!\n", ch);

    ...

    execv(container_args[0], container_args);
    printf("Something's wrong!\n");
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    ...

    pipe(pipefd);

    printf("Parent [%5d] - start a container!\n", getpid());

    int container_pid = clone(container_main, container_stack+STACK_SIZE, 
            CLONE_NEWUTS | CLONE_NEWPID | CLONE_NEWNS | CLONE_NEWUSER | SIGCHLD, NULL);


    ...

    close(pipefd[1]);

    ...
    return 0;
}
```

So, in parent process, I `close(pipefd[1]);`, then, if I read from `read(pipefd[0], &ch, 1);` in child, I'll continue jobs in child process. That make sense.

But when I printed the value of `ch`, it's `0`, I think it should be `-1`, which means EOF.

So can anyone tell me why I read `0` from fd[0] in child instead of EOF?

Comment: `read()` returns `0` on EOF... it returns `-1` for errors.

Comment: If the other end of the pipe is closed, you expect `read` to return 0 and not modify `ch` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read()` returns `0` on `EOF`... it returns `-1` for errors, so if the other end of the pipe is closed, you expect read to return `0` and not modify ch at all.

That's my mistake, I expected to print EOF to `-1` but `read()` have already deal with `EOF` and return `0`.

Thanks Dmitri & William Pursell